# Raspberry pi lirc irw connect: connection refused

Tags: infrared, lirc

since days i try getting irw to work after having installed lirc.

I am using raspian, always freshly updated / upgraded. For lirc i am using the latest version of 2nd of june which is 0.10.0 from lirc.org

Until now i did:

- install lirc
- connecting a receiver TSOP
- testing with **mode2 -d /dev/lirc0** and seeing the raw data space/pulse coming in to the assigned GPIO

But following problem persists:

Calling ''irw''( without parameters ) only tells me:

**connect: No such file or directory**

Calling ''irw /dev/lirc0'' tells me the error message:

**connect: Connection refused**

Now i am at the end of googleing around and hope for a helpful answer out of the community.

Thanks in advance!

best regards
Franz

Answer (score 0):

You don't bring much information about what lirc or OS version you are using. There are vast differences between the "old" 0.9.0 lirc still present in the debian universe, and the modern currently at 0.9.4d.

That said, the short story is that  irw reads data from a socket created by lircd. To get irw working you need to start lircd in a way which depends on your OS and lirc version. lircd reads raw data from /dev/lirc0, decodes it and makes it available on (typically) /var/run/lirc/lircd. This is where irw expects decoded data.

I'd suggest you read http://lirc.org/html/configuration-guide.html which explains the configuration. Note that this is for a modern setup, though.

EDIT: typos

Comment: Hi leamas, thank you for answering my question! I edited it and added my OS and lirc version. What i wondered about was that the raw pulse/spaces could be seen but having problems with irw. I did already but i will again thoroughly read the cofig guide. But if you have a new helpful hint for me please let me know... Thank you!

Comment: Well, that mode2 works show that the kernel send the raw input timing data and looks OK. However, irw needs decoded data, so directing irw to /dev/lirc0 makes no sense. Instead, you need to start the lircd.service and look at the data on  the lircd output socket. However, for this to work you need to configure lirc_options.conf with driver and device and also add the proper config file for your remote to /etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d

Comment: BTW, given that /dev/lirc0 provides timing data (pulse/space) you could _use --driver default --device /dev/lirc0_.  That's a starter, though you still need a config file.

Comment: Also, note that the 0.10.0 actually is 0.10.0rc1 - there might be all sorts of dragons here. The last packaged version for Debian (stretch) is 0,9,4c, but it's actually no difference from upstream 0.9.4d since all the 0.9.4d patches are applied. Please report issues on 0.10.0 at upstream tracker http://sf.net/p/lirc

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers and comments! That helped me to solve the problems i had.

I am working as user 'pi'. Installing lirc i did as 'sudo'. So the lirc.conf etc had the wrong rights which i changed applying ''chmod 777'' to the appropriate files.

I hope my experience in using the raspberry and raspbian gets to a higher level so i can give answers to others if required.

best regards
Franz